# Form + croppie для фото, при редактировании формы, croppie сам режет фото при сохранении, что с этим делать?

Tags: javascript

Есть форма, в форме поля импут и т.д, так же я подключил плагин croppie, для того чтобы обрезать фото на лету в реальном времени.

При добавлении информации в форме и фото, все окей, обрезает и сохраняет.

Редактирую я эти данные которые сохранил, при каждом сохранении данных, не трогая фото, у меня режется фотка и делает это croppie, и становиться все меньше и меньше.

В документации я нашел такое, я так понимаю это то что надо, если фотку не трогал то она не уходит на сохранения, если трогал, то уходит.

update(croppie)Croppie
Triggered when a drag or zoom occurs

```
$('.my-croppie').on('update.croppie', function(ev, cropData) {});
// or
document.getElementById('another-croppie').addEventListener('update', function(ev) { var cropData = ev.detail; });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я примерно понимаю в чем дело:

```
viewport: {
width: 250,
height: 250,
type: 'rawcanvas' 
},
boundary: {
width: '100%',
height: 300
}
```

Если поставить так:

```
viewport: {
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
type: 'rawcanvas' 
},
```

Все окей, фотка не режется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но есть но, теперь нельзя резать фото, пропадают по бокам ползунки, можно только увеличивать.

**Кто как решал данную проблему?**

Сделал пример, но чет фото не выводит, хотя у меня работает на демо сайте.

```js
 //Выводим выбранное фото 1
  var frontViewEditor = $('#frontViewEditor').croppie({
    enableOrientation: true,

    showZoomer: true, //ползунок увеличить, уменьшить
    enableResize: true, //обрезания через двигание рамок снизу, справа
    mouseWheelZoom: 'ctrl',

    viewport: {
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      type: 'rawcanvas' //где вывод фото выбранного, круг circle, квадрат rawcanvas
    },
    boundary: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 300
    }
  });
  
    frontViewEditor.croppie('bind', {
    url: 'https://kartinkin.net/uploads/posts/2021-07/1625835347_17-kartinkin-com-p-chasovoi-mekhanizm-oboi-krasivie-20.jpg'
  });

  //кнопка выбрать фото
  $('#croppie-input').on('change', function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('#frontViewEditor').croppie('bind', {
        url: e.target.result
      });
    }
    //$('#opnfoto').show();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });

  //кнопка повернуть картинку на лево
  $("#rotateLeft").click(function() {
    frontViewEditor.croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
  });
  //кнопка повернуть картинку на право
  $("#rotateRight").click(function() {
    frontViewEditor.croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
  });


  //Выводим выбранное фото 2
  var backViewEditor = $('#backViewEditor').croppie({
    enableOrientation: true,

    showZoomer: true, //ползунок увеличить, уменьшить
    enableResize: true, //обрезания через двигание рамок снизу, справа
    mouseWheelZoom: 'ctrl',

    viewport: {
      width: 250,
      height: 250,
      type: 'rawcanvas' //где вывод фото выбранного, круг circle, квадрат rawcanvas
    },
    boundary: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 300
    }
  });
  
    backViewEditor.croppie('bind', {
    url: 'https://kartinkin.net/uploads/posts/2021-07/1625835347_17-kartinkin-com-p-chasovoi-mekhanizm-oboi-krasivie-20.jpg'
  });
  //кнопка выбрать фото
  $('#croppie-input2').on('change', function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      backViewEditor.croppie('bind', {
        url: e.target.result
      });
    }
    $('#opnfoto2').show();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  });

  //кнопка повернуть картинку на лево
  $("#rotateLeft2").click(function() {
    backViewEditor.croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
  });
  //кнопка повернуть картинку на право
  $("#rotateRight2").click(function() {
    backViewEditor.croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
  });
  
  
  
    //показывает сколько фоток выбрано в кнопке загрузить фото
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.inputhid');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    let label = input.nextElementSibling,
      labelVal = label.querySelector('.lphbt').innerText;

    input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      let countFiles = '';
      if (this.files && this.files.length >= 1)
        countFiles = this.files.length;

      if (countFiles)
        label.querySelector('.lphbt').innerText = 'Выбрано фото: ' + countFiles;
      else
        label.querySelector('.lphbt').innerText = labelVal;
    });
  });
```

```css
.cont{
  margin: 50px;
}
.loadphoto {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.inputhid {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.lphb {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #38A19D;
  background: #38A19D;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.lphb:hover {
  border: 1px solid #133111;
  background: #133111;
  color: #fff;
}
.croppbtn{
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.croppbtn button {
width: 50%;
display: block;
padding: 11px 20px 11px 20px;
line-height:14px;
background: #8FEAA7;
border-radius: 5px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 13px;
border: 0;
}
.croppbtn button:hover {
  background: #133111;
  color: #fff;
}
.croppbtn button:last-child{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.croppbtn button:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}


.lphb,
.croppbtn,
.croppbtn button{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.croppbtn button,.lphb {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}



















html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/croppie/croppie.css" />
<script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/croppie/croppie.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont">

<!-- Загрузка фото 1 -->
<div class="loadphoto">
  <input type="file" name="frontView" accept="image/*" id="croppie-input" class="inputhid">
  <label for="croppie-input" class="lphb">
      <div class="lphbt">Выбрать фото вид спереди</div>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="opnfoto" style="display: none">
  <div class="croppbtn">
    <button type="button" id="rotateLeft" data-deg="-90"><i class="icon-crol"></i> Повернуть<br />на лево</button>
    <button type="button" id="rotateRight" data-deg="90">Повернуть<br />на право <i class="icon-cror"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id="frontViewEditor"></div>
</div>

<!-- Загрузка фото 2 -->
<div class="loadphoto">
  <input type="file" name="backView" accept="image/*" id="croppie-input2" class="inputhid">
  <label for="croppie-input2" class="lphb">
      <div class="lphbt">Выбрать фото вид сзади</div>
  </label>
</div>

<div id="opnfoto2" style="display: none">
  <div class="croppbtn">
    <button type="button" id="rotateLeft2" data-deg="-90"><i class="icon-crol"></i> Повернуть<br />на лево</button>
    <button type="button" id="rotateRight2" data-deg="90">Повернуть<br />на право <i class="icon-cror"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id="backViewEditor"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: А что если по дефолту грузить так, viewport: {
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
type: 'rawcanvas' 
},   но если я хочу изменить фото, сделать поверх как бы клик, я кликаю и становиться так и можно стороны двигать, резать viewport: {
width: 250,
height: 250,
type: 'rawcanvas' 
},

Comment: Есть еще такая мысля в голове, а что если сделать определение, ну если я обрезал что-то, то он определяет и сохраняет, ну перезаписывает, а если я не резал то он не трогает фотку.

Comment: Есть еще идея, а что если просто как я подгружаю уже загруженные фото в кроппие окнах, но просто их показывать, и сделать кнопку, если я хочу править фотки, то нажимаю кнопку резать, и тогда у меня как бы активируются окна кропие эти где фото и появляются шкала и чтоб сжимать фото снизу и справа.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем помогли реализовать, на просторах интернета такое не найдешь.
**Делюсь )**

Не совсем все просто с этим кропие, много замутов.
Решили активировать его по кнопке редактировать, и можно отменить изменения.
Нажал редактировать и кропие активировался и можно резать уже загруженные эти фотки, ну или добавить новую фотку.

В js, много чего описано.

```js
  let frontEditorEnabled = 0;
  let backEditorEnabled = 0;

  let frontViewEditor;
  let backViewEditor;

  // базовая инициализация картинок-заглушек, вместо редактора фото
  function init() {
    let front = $('#frontViewEditor').data('image');
    let back = $('#backViewEditor').data('image');

    $('#frontViewEditor').html('<img src="' + front + '" class="zapho">');
    $('#backViewEditor').html('<img src="' + back + '" class="zapho">');

    uploadImage('front');
    uploadImage('back');
  }
  init();

  // включаем редактор фото
  function enableCrop(block, imageCreate) {

    $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').empty();

    let image = $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').data('image');
    let editorView = (block === 'front') ? frontViewEditor : backViewEditor;

    editorView = $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').croppie({
      viewport: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        type: 'rawcanvas' //где вывод фото выбранного, круг circle, квадрат square
      },
      boundary: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 300
      },

      enableOrientation: true,

      mouseWheelZoom: 'ctrl',
      enableResize: true, //обрезания через двигание рамок снизу, справа
      showZoomer: true, //ползунок увеличить, уменьшить
      enableZoom: true
    });

    if (imageCreate != true) {
      editorView.croppie('bind', {
        url: image
      });
    }

    if (block == 'front') {
      changeStatusFront(1);
    }
    if (block == 'back') {
      changeStatusBack(1);
    }
  }

  // смена статуса редактирования frontview
  function changeStatusFront(status) {
    frontEditorEnabled = status;
    if (status == 0) {
      $("#rotateLeft, #rotateRight").attr({
        "disabled": "disabled"
      });
    } else {
      $("#rotateLeft, #rotateRight").attr({
        "disabled": false
      });
    }
  }

  // смена статуса редактирования backview
  function changeStatusBack(status) {
    backEditorEnabled = status;
    if (status == 0) {
      $("#rotateLeft2, #rotateRight2").attr({
        "disabled": "disabled"
      });
    } else {
      $("#rotateLeft2, #rotateRight2").attr({
        "disabled": false
      });
    }
  }

  // загрузка фото
  function uploadImage(block) {
    //кнопка выбрать фото
    $('#croppie-input-' + block).on('change', function() {
      if (this.files[0]) {
        destroyCrop(block);
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
          enableCrop(block, true);
          $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').croppie('bind', {
            url: e.target.result
          });

          // меняем статус редактора и прячем кнопку редактирования
          if (block == 'front') {
            changeStatusFront(1);
            $("#editorFrontButton").hide();
          }
          if (block == 'back') {
            changeStatusBack(1);
            $("#editorBackButton").hide();
          }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
    });
  }

  // дестрой редактора, при отключении сносит все данные и выводит дефолт
  function destroyCrop(block) {
    $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').croppie('destroy');

    let image = $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').data('image');
    $('#' + block + 'ViewEditor').html('<img src="' + image + '" class="zapho">');

    // вырубаем редактор
    if (block == 'front') {
      changeStatusFront(0);
    }
    if (block == 'back') {
      changeStatusBack(0);
    }
  }

  // включение редактора
  $("#editorFrontButton, #editorBackButton").click(function() {
    let status = $(this).attr('data-editor');

    if (status == 0) {
      enableCrop($(this).data('type'));
      // показываем загрузчик
      $("div[data-load-block=" + $(this).data('type') + "]").show();
      // показываем кнопки переворота
      $("button[data-edit-button=" + $(this).data('type') + "]").css({
        "display": "flex"
      });
    } else {
      destroyCrop($(this).data('type'));
      // прячем загрузчик фото
      $("div[data-load-block=" + $(this).data('type') + "]").hide();
      // прячем кнопки переворота
      $("button[data-edit-button=" + $(this).data('type') + "]").css({
        "display": "none"
      });
    }
    $(this).text(((status == 0) ? 'Отменить изменения' : 'Редактировать фото')).attr({
      'data-editor': (status == 0) ? 1 : 0
    });
  });

  //кнопка повернуть картинку на лево
  $("#rotateLeft").click(function() {
    if (frontEditorEnabled === 1) {
      $('#frontViewEditor').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
    }
  });
  //кнопка повернуть картинку на право
  $("#rotateRight").click(function() {
    if (frontEditorEnabled === 1) {
      $('#frontViewEditor').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
    }
  });


  //кнопка повернуть картинку на лево
  $("#rotateLeft2").click(function() {
    if (backEditorEnabled === 1) {
      $('#backViewEditor').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
    }
  });
  //кнопка повернуть картинку на право
  $("#rotateRight2").click(function() {
    if (backEditorEnabled === 1) {
      $('#backViewEditor').croppie('rotate', parseInt($(this).data('deg')));
    }
  });



  (function() {

    let form = $('#validform');
    //функция для кнопок, в форме две разные кнопки, при клике каждая кнопка отправляет в свой актион на обработку данные с формы. береться урл при клике и передаеться в App.sendAx
    $("#addsend, #addchernovik").click(function() {
      form.data('url', $(this).data('url'))
    });

    form.on('submit', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      form.find('.ax-result').removeClass('successform error').html('');

      let formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

      let preparingError = false;
      let preparedImages = 0;

      // сколько фоток редактируется
      let countActive = 0;

      // если редактор активен то отпраляем фото
      if (frontEditorEnabled) {
        countActive++;
        //забираем измененную картинку из Croppie в formData для отправки
        $('#frontViewEditor').croppie('result', {
          type: 'blob',
          size: 'original' //оставляем оригинальный размер картинки, не уменьшает, а обрезает что обрезали
        }).then(function(blob) {
          formData.append('images[0]', blob);
          preparedImages++;
        }).catch(function(e) {
          preparingError = true;
          console.log(e);
        });
      }

      // если редактор активен то отпраляем фото
      if (backEditorEnabled) {
        countActive++;
        //забираем измененную картинку из Croppie в formData для отправки
        $('#backViewEditor').croppie('result', {
          type: 'blob',
          size: 'original' //оставляем оригинальный размер картинки, не уменьшает, а обрезает что обрезали
        }).then(function(blob) {
          formData.append('images[1]', blob);
          preparedImages++;
        }).catch(function(e) {
          preparingError = true;
          console.log(e)
        });
      }

      // ждем картинки от Croppie
      (function waitForImages() {
        // Прекращаем ожидание в случае ошибки Croppie
        if (preparingError) {
          form.find('.ax-result').addClass('error').html('Failed to read croppie image');
          return;
        }
        // Отправляем данные формы с картинками из Croppie когда они готовы
        if (preparedImages === countActive) {
          //берем url актиона из кнопки и подставляем
          let url = form.data('url');
          App.sendAx(url, formData, {
            silence: true,
            successFunction: function(d) {
              form.find('.ax-result').addClass('successform').html(d.message);
              form.find('.ax-form').hide();
              //перекидывает к валидации, когда форма исчезает
              document.getElementById('goer').scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "smooth"
              });
            },
            errorFunction: function(d) {
              alert("error");
              return false;
              form.find('.ax-result').addClass('error').html(d.message);
              form.find('.ax-form').show();
            }
          });
          return;
        }
        setTimeout(waitForImages, 100);
      })();

    });
  })();
```

```css
.cont{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 500px;
}
#editorFrontButton,
#editorBackButton {
display: block;
padding: 13px 20px 13px 20px;
line-height:14px;
background: #133111;
border-radius: 5px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 13px;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#editorFrontButton:hover,
#editorBackButton:hover {
    background: #38A19D;
}
.loadphoto {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.inputhid {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.lphb {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 55px;
  border: 1px solid #38A19D;
  background: #38A19D;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.lphb:hover {
  border: 1px solid #133111;
  background: #133111;
  color: #fff;
}
.croppbtn{
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.croppbtn button {
width: 50%;
display: block;
padding: 11px 20px 11px 20px;
line-height:14px;
background: #8FEAA7;
border-radius: 5px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 13px;
border: 0;
}
.croppbtn button:hover {
  background: #133111;
  color: #fff;
}
.croppbtn button:last-child{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.croppbtn button:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.zapho{
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.lphb,
.croppbtn,
.croppbtn button{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.croppbtn button,.lphb {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}



















html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/croppie/croppie.css" />
<script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/croppie/croppie.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont">
<!-- Загрузка фото 1 -->
            <div data-load-block="front" class="loadphoto" style="display: none">
              <input type="file" name="frontView" accept="image/*" data-type="front" id="croppie-input-front" class="inputhid">
              <label for="croppie-input-front" class="lphb">
                <div>
                  <i class="icon-addphoto"></i>
                  <div class="lphbt">Выбрать фото вид спереди</div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div id="opnfoto-front">
              <div class="croppbtn">
                <button type="button" data-edit-button="front" style="display: none" disabled id="rotateLeft" data-deg="-90"><i class="icon-crol"></i> Повернуть<br />на лево</button>
                <button type="button" data-edit-button="front" style="display: none" disabled id="rotateRight" data-deg="90">Повернуть<br />на право <i class="icon-cror"></i></button>
              </div>

              <a type="button" data-type="front" href="javascript:void(0);" data-editor="0" id="editorFrontButton">Редактировать фото</a>

              <div data-image="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/18/ed/57/18ed57ad2a947fa365bca48bb89f3590.jpg" id="frontViewEditor"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Загрузка фото 2 -->
            <div data-load-block="back" class="loadphoto" style="display: none">
              <input type="file" name="backView" accept="image/*" data-type="back" id="croppie-input-back" class="inputhid">
              <label for="croppie-input-back" class="lphb">
                <div>
                  <i class="icon-addphoto"></i>
                  <div class="lphbt">Выбрать фото вид сзади</div>
                </div>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div id="opnfoto-back">
              <div class="croppbtn">
                <button disabled data-edit-button="back" style="display: none" type="button" id="rotateLeft2" data-deg="-90"><i class="icon-crol"></i> Повернуть<br />на лево</button>
                <button disabled data-edit-button="back" style="display: none" type="button" id="rotateRight2" data-deg="90">Повернуть<br />на право <i class="icon-cror"></i></button>
              </div>

              <a type="button" data-type="back" href="javascript:void(0);" data-editor="0" id="editorBackButton">Редактировать фото</a>

              <div data-image="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/18/ed/57/18ed57ad2a947fa365bca48bb89f3590.jpg" id="backViewEditor"></div>
            </div>
</div>
```